# Understanding 'percepset' instead of 'percepisset'

Tags: verbs, morphology, conjugation, perfect-tense

When looking at the [L&S entry for *percipio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=percipio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), I came across a surprising perfect form: *percepset*.
The contraction *percepisset > percepset* lookst similar to *cogitavisset > cogitasset*.
Are contractions similar to *percepset* common for verbs whose perfect stem does not end in V?
I do not recall ever seeing any.
If such forms are found, is it specific to some eras, verbs, forms, or contexts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe they are very rare, but it is possible to find some others. I have found *vixet* in the Aeneid:

> [Publius Vergilius Maro, *Aeneis* 11.118]
>
> apparat, his mecum decuit concurrere telis:
>   **uixet** cui uitam deus aut sua dextra dedisset.
>   nunc ite et miseris supponite ciuibus ignem.'

On which comments Maurus Servius Honoratus, a late fourth-century and early fifth-century grammarian:

> [Maurus Servius Honoratus, *In Vergilii Aeneidos Libros*:]
>
> 11.118.1 **vixet** pro 'vixisset': et est syncope.
>
> 3.152.1 INSERTAS aut clatratas; aut non seratas, ut sit quasi 'inseratas', id est non clausas, et dictum, quomodo 'asprosque molares' pro 'asperos', conpostus' pro 'conpositus', '**vixet**' pro 'vixisset'. {⁴³vel 'insertas fenestras' quas lumine suo luna inseruerat, ab inserendo, quod se per rimas insereret.

So he considers it simply a syncope. As I can only find any forms on *-ixet* in the Aeneid, it may have been invented by Virgil *metri causa*, but possibly with some licence based not only on poetry but also on archaic variants, when morphology had been less fixed.

I can find *-pset* only in two sources (one of whom is Cicero):

> [Marcus Tullius Cicero, De Officiis 3.98.9]
>
> Quod ni Palamedi perspicax prudentia
>   Istius **percepset** malitiosam audaciam
>   Fide sacratae ius perpetuo falleret."
>
> [Anonymi Comici et Tragici, Tragoediae Poetarum Incertorum 59]
>
> Quod ní Palamedi pérspicax prudéntia
>   Istíus **percepset** málitiosam audáciam,
>   Fidé sacratae iús perpetuo fálleret.

Answer (score 2):

András Cser's "[The nature of phonological conditioning in Latin inflectional allomorphy](https://akademiai.com/doi/pdf/10.1556/ALing.62.2015.1.1)" seems to say contraction like this occurs somewhat often in the perfect forms of verbs that have perfect stems ending in /s/ (as in Cerberus's example *vixet ~ vixisset*), and gives a few examples. Cser doesn't mention any patterns of variation, but he does offer a phonological analysis:

> #### 2.3.2.2. Vowel deletion after [s]
>
> One minor point of complication involves *s*-final perfective stems (excluding *-ls-, -rs-*) combining with *is*-affixes. In more than just a handful of cases the vowelless affix variant appears, and the number of adjacent [s]’s is reduced.
> Thus *derexisti ∼ derexti* ‘arrange’ PresPerf2Sing, *divisisse ∼ divisse*
> ‘divide’ PerfInf, *accessistis ∼ accestis* ‘approach’ PresPerf2Plur,
> *admisisse ∼ admisse* ‘send to’ PerfInf, and many others. On the face of
> it this looks like the loss of an [is] sequence specifically after [s] in these
> particular constructions (as is the tradition, see Leumann 1977, 598), but it
> is more economical to analyse the disappearance of the vowel as being the
> same allomorphic variation as that seen after vowel-final stems, and the
> disappearance of [s] as resulting from an independently motivated phonological process of degemination, because in this case we do not need any
> extra processes – apart from stipulating the somewhat odd context [s]
> for the otherwise postvocalic morpheme variants.

(p. 13)

In *[Latin Hexameter Verse: An Aid to Composition](https://books.google.com/books?id=NvkVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA212&lpg=PA212&dq=%22vixti%22+Latin&source=bl&ots=GF__v8UKLn&sig=b8os1zhh8i9oDbLkjd9vaF_Kknw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi37-HtvpbbAhVizIMKHWy3A8UQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22vixti%22%20Latin&f=false),* by Samuel Edward Winbolt (1903), I found mention of the forms *vixti* (for *vixisti*), *extinxem* (for *extinxissem*), and *finxe* (for *finxisse*) (p. 212).

I can't find any examples of *derexet* for *derexisset,* though.

Other sources that seem to have relevant information:

> Ancient forms of a future perfect in *so*, a perfect and pluperfect subjunctive in *sim* and *sem*, and a perfect infinitive in *se* sometimes occur. They may, in general, be formed by adding these terminations to the second root of the verb; as, *recepso, emissim, ausim* from the obsolete perfect, *ausi*, from *audeo, confexim* and *promissem*: *divisse* and *promisse*. But when the root ends in *x*, and frequently when it ends in *s*, only *o, im, em*, and *e*, etc. are added; as, *jusso, dixis; intellexes, percepset; surrexe, sumse.* *V*, at the end of the root, in the first conjugation, is changed into *s;* as, *levasso, locassim.* *U,* at the end of the root, in the second conjugation, is changed into *es;* as, *habesso, licessit.*  Sometimes the vowel of the present is retained in these forms, though changed in the other parts derived from the second root; as, *capso, faxo (facso), faxim (facsim).*

(*[A grammar of the Latin language; for the use of schools and colleges](https://archive.org/stream/grammaroflatinla00andr_0#page/122),* by E.A. Andrews and S. Stoddard, 1857, p. 122)

Some similar-looking forms seem to have been used as archaic future subjunctives:

> [A "future pluperfect" tense] occurs in Virgil, Aenid, 11, 467, *Jusso,* and was found in Cicero, de Legg. 2, 9, *Jussit,* until altered to *Jusserit* by modern editors.--Not satisfied with Vossius'es formation of it from the future in *ERO,* I derive it from the (contracted*) pluperfect subjunctive, as *Ama'ssem, Amasso* -- *Summo'ssem, Sumosso* -- *Recep'sem, Recepso* -- *Effec'sem,* or *Effexem, Effexo* -- *Jus'sem, Jusso* -- *Audi'ssem, Audisso.* -- The verbs in *UI* took *ESSO,* as *Habesso,* in Cicero, de Legg. 2, 8.

(*[Latin prosody made easy](https://books.google.com/books?id=RLNWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=habesso&source=bl&ots=eoQCJfCYPn&sig=Et2XUD1yHtgKnlEB52ozUkkPhJA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7np3L4JbbAhUQ71MKHSFlDrwQ6AEITzAL#v=onepage&q&f=false),* by John Carey, 1819, pp. 93-94)

On p. 220, Carey gives a list of a number of other forms "all found in classic authors" that show this kind of "syncope of *IS, ISS,* or *SIS*"; I have rearranged them into groups by their endings, and bolded the ones where the standard perfect stem doesn't seem to end in /s/:

- -sti (active perf. ind. 2s): 
  *Scripsti, Conscripsti, Praescripsti, Subrepsti, Consumpsti, **Cœpsti**, Mansti, Sensti, Misti, Promisti, Amisti,  Dixti, Intellexti, Advexti, Prospexti, Aspexti, Luxti, Abduxti, Adduxti, Induxti, Subduxti, Instruxti, Depinxti, Devinxti, Emunxti, Immersti, Tersti, Exclusti, Revixti, Exstinxti, Percusti*
- -stis (active perf. ind. 2p) 
  *Accestis*
- -se (active perf. inf.): 
  *Scripse, Carpse, Sumpse, Consumpse, **Cepse**,  Promisse, Elisse, Divisse, Admisse, Decesse, Dixe, Illuxe, Illexe, Advexe, Circumspexe, Surrexe, Abstraxe, Prospexe, Despexe*
- -sem (active pluperf. subj. 1s): 
  *Conclussem, Faxem, Interdixem,  Exstinxem*
- -ses (active pluperf. subj. 2s): 
  *Intellexes*
- -set (active pluperf. subj. 3s): 
  ***Percepset**, Recesset*
- -semus (active pluperf. subj. 1p): 
  *Erepsemus*

Note that despite what Cser says about *-rs-* being excluded, Carey mentions some contracted words ending in *-rsti.*

*[The Art of Latin Poetry](https://books.google.com/books?id=xEgQAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=habesso&source=bl&ots=JYaKRduxcQ&sig=IqXryodVDW8yth67WqZuAX6CpoY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7np3L4JbbAhUQ71MKHSFlDrwQ6AEIUjAM#v=onepage&q=habesso&f=false)* (1828) specifically mentions "omitting the syllable *si* before *sti*" as a "contraction chiefly used by the comic writers ; but Vergil has accestis, for accessistis, Æn. i 205; and Horace evasti for evasisti, *Sat.* ii. 7. 68" and gives a separate description of "rejecting *is* or *iss* , after *x*,; Direxti, for direxisti, *Virg. Æn.* vi. 57. Extinxtem, for extinxissem, *Id. Æn.* iv. 606. Surrexe, for surrexisse, *Hor. Sat.* i. 9. 73" (p. 41).